# User details store best practies

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, architecture, credentials

It is possible to extends from
`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`
and create your own implementation of it to hold more information about a user, not only username/password/authorities. So, we can make something like

```
public class CustomUser extends User {
    private MyEntityUser user;
    // getters/setters/contructor
}
```

And do not load from database user information more than one time?

Is that legal? Or exists another palce for this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one of the good ways to solve your problem. From the Java documentation, there are three appropriate approaches:

> Developers may use this class directly [1], subclass it [2], or write their
>   own `UserDetails` implementation from scratch [3].

On one of my projects I've picked up the third strategy and used the following hierarchy:

```
class AccountAuthDetails extends Account implements UserDetails { ... }
class Account { ... }
```

I didn't have a need in `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` then.